# Find the derivative of a function that contains a sum

Tags: derivatives, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

If $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{n\cdot3^n}{(x-3)}^n}$$ find $f''(-2)$.

---

I know that, by ratio test, the previous sum converges iff $x\in(0,6)$.

I did:

$$\begin{matrix}
f'(x)&=&\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{n\cdot3^n}{(x-3)}^n}\right)'&=&
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{n\cdot3^n}n{(x-3)}^{n-1}}&=&
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{3^n}{(x-3)}^{n-1}}
\\
f''(x)&=&\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{3^n}{(x-3)}^{n-1}}\right)'&=&
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{3^n}(n-1){(x-3)}^{n-2}},
\end{matrix}$$

so I did the radio test on the last sum:

$$\begin{matrix}
&&\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|} \\
&=&\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left|\dfrac{{(-1)}^{n+2}n{(x-3)}^{n-1}}{3^{n+1}}\dfrac{3^n}{{(-1)}^{n+1}(n-1){(x-3)}^{n-2}}\right|}\\
&=&\dfrac{|x-3|}{3}\underbrace{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left|\dfrac{n}{n-1}\right|}}_{=\:1}\\
&\Rightarrow&|x-3|<3\\
&\Rightarrow&x\in(0,6),&
\end{matrix}$$

and since $-2\not\in(0,6)$ we cannot find $f''(-2)$.

---

First question: is my reasoning right?

If yes, to my amazement the radius of convergence of both functions are the same. Out of curiosity, why is this happening? The convergence can be generalize to $n$-th derivative?

Thank you!

Comment: @Crostul but [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+f%27%27(-2)+of+f(x)+%3D+sum+of+n%3D1+to+infinity+of+(((-1)%5E(n%2B1))%2F(n*3%5En))*(x-3)%5En) says another thing...

Comment: Crostul's result holds under condition that we are inside the range of convergence. Outside of it, it's a value you can assign to the sum in the generalized fashion (similar to what you can do to the famous 1+2+3+...=-1/12 sum), but technically, it doesn't converge so it has no value.

Comment: Ah... I love the $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$. Ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it always works. It can be proved (this is a standard result about power series) that if the power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$ has radius of convergence $R$ then;

1. the radius of convergence of the pwer series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n(z-a)^{n-1}$ is also $R$;
2. $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n\right)'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n(z-a)^{n-1}$.

Comment: *(I think this is the first time you answer one of my questions (I take a look to your answers and they are incredible))* Wow! amazings properties! Thank you.

Comment: @manooooh I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of finding $f''(-2)$ with 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{n\cdot3^n}{(x-3)}^n}$$
then consider the following.

**Method 1**

Since
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \, \left(1 - \frac{x}{3}\right)^{n} = \ln\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)
\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \frac{1}{x} \\
f''(x) &= - \frac{1}{x^2}
\end{align}

**Method 2**

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \, \left(1 - \frac{x}{3}\right)^{n} \\
f'(x) &= \frac{1}{3} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{3 - x}{3} \right)^{n} = \frac{1}{3 \, \left(1 - \left( 1 - \frac{x}{3} \right) \right)} = \frac{1}{x} \\
f''(x) &= - \frac{1}{x^2}.
\end{align}

The value sought can now be obtained by setting $x = -2$.